# MySQL: Return Count of 0 for Items Not Found in "WHERE IN" List

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a page listing 100 auctions and I would like to display the number of bids per itemid. Here is what I have so far (using just 4 auctions in this example):

```
SELECT itemid, COUNT(*) as count FROM bids WHERE itemid IN(487359,487342,487339,487338) GROUP BY itemid
```

This displays the number of bids... but only if a bids (and itemid) actually exist in the bid table. Items that have no bid will not have an itemid in the bids table. How do I return a count of "0" for these?

I tried the following, but these don't work either:

```
IFNULL(COUNT(*),0) and COLEASCE(COUNT(*),0)
```

**UPDATE**

Here is some example data:

Bids Table

---

itemid    |    bid   |

487359    |   1.00   |
487359    |   2.00   |
487359    |   2.50   |
487342    |   8.20   |
487338    |   1.00   |

What actually happens:

---

itemid    | #of bids |

487359    |    3     |
487342    |    1     |
487338    |    1     |

What I would like returned:

itemid    | #of bids |

487359    |    3     |
487342    |    1     |
487339    |    0     |
487338    |    1     |

Note that item "487339" isn't found in the auctions table because there are no bids recorded for that item. I would like mysql to return 0 for these.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: if you want to count the items that does not exists, you should have a table with all your items and join on it. If you don't what a physical table, you can create a virtual table with a WITH statement. I see no other approach to your issue.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Yes Strawberry, I had considered just using my existing query and if the itemid wasn't found in the result (using php if/then check), simply display 0 instead. I was hoping there might be a really simple MySQL trick though, but I guess not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT i.id as itemid, COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) as count
  FROM items i LEFT OUTER JOIN bids b ON i.id = b.itemid
 WHERE i.id IN (487359, 487342, 487339, 487338)
 GROUP BY i.id
```

This will always return the items specified — so long as the record exists — and a 0 if there are no bids found. Because an `OUTER JOIN` is being used, if you need to add any filter criteria to the bids, be sure to add it to the `OUTER JOIN` with `AND`. Do not add `bids` criteria to the `WHERE`, otherwise your `OUTER JOIN` will be treated as an `INNER JOIN`, removing all records with 0 bids.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use conditional summations here:

```sql
SELECT
    itemid,
    SUM(itemid IN (487359, 487342, 487339, 487338, ...)) AS count
FROM bids
GROUP BY
    itemid;
```

However, a better approach, especially if the list of `itemid` be long, would be to place these values in a separate table `items` and then do a left join with `bids`:

```sql
SELECT
    b.itemid,
    COUNT(i.itemid) AS count
FROM bids b
LEFT JOIN items i            -- contains 487359, 487342, 487339, 487338, ...
    ON i.itemid = b.itemid
GROUP BY
    b.itemid;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in the top query, it returns many hundreds of results instead of just the 100 itemids requested. As for the second query, I'm listing 100 auctions in pagination and there are many thousands of auctions in my main "items" table (along with non-auction items). In my script, I first retrieved the 100 auction items to be displayed, got their ids and wanted to do one single query to get the number of bids for just those ids. Otherwise I have to do a single mysql query in a PHP loop 100x for each item.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.